# C++ Eigen multi-threading in Array operation

Tags: c++, multithreading, eigen

I have a question regarding the Array operations in Eigen (basically matrix element-wise operations).

Are such operations (+,-,*,/) parallelized in Eigen (when using OpenMP)? The doc does not specify it (c.f. [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html)), however such operations would be expected to be parallelized since it would be pretty straightforward I guess.

Example:

```
MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Zero(100,100);
MatrixXd B = MatrixXd::Ones(100,100);

MatrixXd C = A.array() + B.array(); // element-wise addition
MatrixXd D = A.array() / B.array(); // element-wise division
```

It would be great if it was parallelized. I have a lots of these element-wise operations in my code, and it would be heavier to redefine all of these with OpenMP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You won't note any difference anyways with 100x100 matrices.

Comment: This was a dummy example to explain my problem. The final code will be apply to much larger matrices.

Answer (score 0):

The Eigen [web site](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) lists the few cases that take advantage of multithreading.

> Currently, the following algorithms can make use of multi-threading:
>
> general dense matrix - matrix products
>      PartialPivLU
>      row-major-sparse * dense vector/matrix products
>      ConjugateGradient with Lower|Upper as the UpLo template parameter.
>      BiCGSTAB with a row-major sparse matrix format.
>      LeastSquaresConjugateGradient

This does not exclude SIMD operations, so those will still be used.

Comment: Indeed, I had a look at this page (c.f. my post). I don't understand what you mean by "This does not exclude SIMD operations, so those will still be used.", do you mean that SIMD operations as array operations support multi-threading in Eigen? Thanks

Comment: He probably means that you will still have SIMD (vector) operations within each thread

Comment: Ok, thanks. At least, if it is parallelized on the rows or the columns, it will be more efficient, than purely sequential computations I guess ?

Comment: I meant that you will have SIMD (vector) operations within the *one* thread (unless you manually introduce more). It will be vectorized column wise, as that's the storage order for `MatrixXd`. You can group the operations together to minimize the number of temporaries, as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I understand. Vectorized operations will speed up the computations on arrays. However, it would be even more efficient if these array operations would be multi-threaded. I use several cores in other part of my code, these supplementary cores are unused during array operations, which is a waste of resources.

I guess, I will have to redefine array operations by myself to benefit from multi-threading. I will get in touch with the Eigen team to see if this is planned or if I can contribute.

Thanks again

Comment: You can write your expressions as blocks using OMP's thread index for separating them. See for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845724/eigen-openmp-no-parallelisation-due-to-false-sharing-and-thread-overhead/41847107#41847107).